# Adding emails without opt in with Mailchimps API

Tags: php, api, mailchimp, mailing-list

i wrote before about passing email data with mailchimps API, Now i kind of learned how to use its API to send data with an  [example](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/downloads/mcapi-simple-subscribe-jquery.zip) they gave in its documentation, but the method they use listSubscribe() its even written in their documentation *"you will not see new members until the link contained in it is clicked!"* [Link to listsubscribe() doc](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.2/listsubscribe.func.php)

Anyone know either a work around to allow adding subscribers without this opt in function, or is not even allowed, i am already looking in its documentation but no success, i wrote to them today, but i guess they all take a few days to answer. has anyone hassled with this already? Thanks

Comment: its right on the API page you link to `double_optin`

Comment: If this were possible and that someone ever got a hold of your script, then they could easily add anyone (*without permission*). Makes a lot of sense to me. It's best to leave well enough alone and keep adding them (*yourself*) from within your control panel. ;-)

Comment: Plus, instead of waiting on an answer from a message you left them via Email (I presume), would be to chat with them via their LIVE chat method.

Comment: Thanx, but how would i implement the double_optin method, the listsubscribe is like this if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], '') === true) so it thried the same way the double_optin but it didnt work ($api->double_optin($list_id, $_GET['email'], '') === true)  any ideas how to implement the double_optin and @Fred the live chat is offline now.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Well I for one am unable to give you a definite answer, but I tend to think that this would not be possible, however I could be wrong. Best thing then would be to wait for their response. Hopefully they will give you a definite answer, instead of answers coming from outside their organization. It's best to hear it from "the horse's mouth" *as it were*. ;-)

Comment: ok thanx, @cmorrissey any tips how to implement the double_optin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in order to take out the default opt-in function which sends the user a confirmation email instead of the emails going directly to ur email DB  just put $double_optin=false by default it was $double_optin=true (on the MCAPI.class.php gile)
Its that easy, hope this helps for beginner API users like myself.

Comment: **+1** Glad to hear you found a solution.